# oci_bind_by_name() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, oracle11g

I am trying to get codeigniter to run a stored procedure in oracle. I am passing the following into the stored_procedure function:

```
$param = array(array("name"=>"v_organisation_id", "value"=>1, "type"=>"OCI_B_INT", "length"=>-1));
    $query = $this->db->stored_procedure("EXECUTE", "GET_ACCOMMODATION", $param);
```

It is returning the following error:

> oci_bind_by_name() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given

The function sends the parameters into oci_bind_by_name() like this:

```
oci_bind_by_name($this->stmt_id, $param['name'], $param['value'], $param['length'], $param['type']);
```

It says that $param['type'] needs to be long and on the php docs it says that $param['type'] needs to be int $type = SQLT_CHR.

I have tried putting $param['type'] in without the quotes, but it then gives the following error message:

> oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: @micb I tried that, but it gave the second error message above about it being an illegal variable name/number

Comment: sorry my bad i didn't read it all, im looking at the CI source and it looks at though it doesn't create the stored procedure string correctly. Try change `$sql .= $param['name'] . ",";` to `$sql .= ':' . $param['name'] . ",";` and do the `$param['type']` without the quotes. That might work then.

Comment: basically it looks at though its trying to bind a value to the query but there is no :<name> for it to bind to, hence the error oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: Thanks @micb it worked if I put a : in front of the variable name. Now I have a database error and no error number showing :/

Comment: np :) good luck with ur DB error im not so good with oracle DB errors.